# Pattern for parsing method parameters

Tags: regex, scala

I'd like to parse the parameter to a call to the `Messages` object. The parameter is either a string (with quotes) or a variable name or a string with a variable concatenated:

**Examples**

1. `Messages("some string")`
2. `Messages(someVariableName)`
3. `Messages("string"+someVariable)`

**Desired Results**

1. `some string` (notice no quotation marks)
2. `someVariableName`
3. `"string"+someVariable` (with quotes around the string)

How does a regex look like that gives me these results?

Thus far I've tried `Messages\("?([^"]*)"?\)` which works for the first and second example but not for the third

Comment: First: what language are you using? Second: I don't think you can do all of those with only one regex. If you want to keep the quotes on one and remove them on another, I'm pretty sure you'll need two.

Comment: You've posted examples and the desired results. But you haven't shown us what you've tried so far. Please edit your question to include your attempts so far.

Comment: I'm using it in a scala script

Comment: Added my attempts to the question

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex which uses logical OR operator,

```
Messages\("(.*?)(?="\))|Messages\(([^)]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qA2eZ4/1)

**Explanation:**

- `Messages\("(.*?)(?="\))` Captures all the charcters after the string `Messages("` only if it's followed by `")`
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `Messages\(([^)]*)` From the remaining strings, it captures all the characters after the string `Messages("` until the `)` is reached.

Comment: works nicely except when there are to calls on the same line like here: @Messages("test")" @Messages("test12")

Answer (score 0):

`Messages\("([^"]*)"\)|Messages\((.*)\)` should do the trick